# изменение строк TableLayout.Android

Tags: android, tableview

TableLayout, которая  состоит из TableRow c тремя столбцами. Заполняю данные с сервера. Требуется после заполнения 10 строчек заменять верхнюю, а остальные смещаются вниз и последняя строчка соответственно удаляется(то есть таблица постоянно смещается сверху вниз с добавлением нового верхнего элемента)
Как это лучше реализовать, возможно заменить Table row, а остальные сместить,либо можно как то реализовать через ListView и адаптеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С TableLayout вы врядли добьетесь этого. Лучше реализуйте все через SimpleAdapter и ListView. Так как вам нужно только разбрасывать данные, с адаптером вы вообще не наткнетесь на грабли. Когда вы примете JSON массив с сервера вам нужно сначала выполнить проверку на его длину больше 10 объектов. Если он меньше - то заполнять ListView как обычно. Иначе (если больше 10) - то брать только **последние 10 объектов из массива** и заполнять ими ListView. Именно так вы добьетесь желаемого эффекта :)) Могу помочь с кодом

Comment: спасибо.сейчас сам попробую поковыряться!)